# QT Static Library Static Compilation

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, static, static-libraries

My task is to use my library in Windows projects on a computers without istalled Qt. So I want to compile my library with statically linked Qt code.

I do  not understand how to compile my own code to a static library, linking all Qt stuff, used in it, statically. I have downloaded sources of Qt and compiled it statically (QT 5.8.0) with msvc 2015 and added new static qmake in Qt Creator complects. I tried to build my library, it succeded, but using it on other computer, without Qt installed, gets many linker errors **LNK2001** and **LNK2019**.

Here is an example of an error:

```
Error LNK2019 Unresolved External Symbol "public: int __thiscall
QJsonValue::toInt(int)const " (?toInt@QJsonValue@@QBEHH@Z) in function
"public: int __thiscall QJsonValueRef::toInt(void)const "
(?toInt@QJsonValueRef@@QBEHXZ)  ConsoleApplication2 c:\Users\Alex\documents\visualstudio
2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\TcpClient.lib(tcpthreadpart.obj)
```

So, as I understand, all Qt sources were not linked to my library. There are some guides on the internet how to compile an `.exe` with static linking of qt, I have tried them to compile my library, but it failed. Could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

The library itself must be a dynamic library, since that's the only kind that existing tools can link with anything. When you build that library against a static Qt, the library will use Qt statically as you wish.

It seems like you've built a static library, and as such there's no "linking" it to anything. Technically it'd be possible, but there are no tools that do it :(